# Cucumber and/or RSpec with pure Java application using JRuby

Tags: java, rspec, jruby, cucumber

After doing some stuff in Ruby on Rails with Cucumber, RSpec and Ruby BDD in general, comming back to JUnit in my Java apps feels like incredible pain to me. I just love the convenience that Ruby brings into testing.

From what I understand, it should be theoreticaly possible to use Cucumber features, or even RSpec mocking with pure Java application.

**Is someone using Cucumber with Java app in production?**

Last time when I tried hacking JRuby into Java was running it on Google App Engine, which actualy worked, but increased App Engine *startup time* by about 10 seconds, which made it quite useless.

**I am not talking just about web applications.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have gotten Cucumber working with one of our Java web based applications. The basics are I setup a Rails application, because I wanted to use Factory Girl and Active Record to create fixtures, added in Cucumber, and created a post hook that deleted all of the records from the database. It runs pretty well. I wrote up a blog post here:

http://www.vitarara.org/cms/testing_non-ruby_applications_with_cucumber